# Validity of ray optics

Tags: geometric-optics

Why don't we consider 3d objects or even 3d refracting surfaces(2d glass slab) in geometric optics .Why many phenomena is only valid for point size objects (such as refracting from curved surface)?

Comment: Who says "we" don't consider 3d objects in geometric optics? Many situations are usefully simplified to 2d, that doesn't mean geometric optics is invalid in three dimensions! (ray tracing in 3d graphical applications is a clear counterexample)

Comment: @ACuriousMind and what about point objects?

Comment: We absolutely do this!

Answer (score 0):

Ray optics, and acoustics, is a high frequency limiting approximation to the full wave equation.  It can be derived form the wave equation.  It has certain problems like caustics, and does not account for diffraction intrinsically but these can all be corrected.

Rays and closely related to bi-characteristics, the curves of flow that push forward a characteristic surface (wave front) through space in time.  Ray tracing is absolutely valid for three dimensional curved objects.  In fact there is a very famous software for estimating the radar scattering cross section form aircraft called X-patch that uses ray theory to build up the reflected field.